# Saving Python For loop Results

Tags: python, excel, loops, xlwings

```
import xlwings as xw
import datetime

begin_time = datetime.datetime.now()
wbTest = xw.Book('Conventinal UL (S & A - All others) - April 2023 V3 - Dummy Run For Q1 2023.xlsm')

ws1 = wbTest.sheets['Cashflows']
d = {}

for x in range(1,11):
    ws1.range('C3').value = x
    d[x] = ws1.range('C20').value

print(datetime.datetime.now())
print(datetime.datetime.now() - begin_time)
print(d[x])
```

In the above code I am trying to update value in excel range C3 the excel calculates and the answer is in the range C20 I am trying to save loop results but unfortunately it only show the last results not all the results from 1 to 10.

Comment: print (d[x]) is outside the loop so will only be called once at the end. Move it inside.

Comment: Or change it to `print(d)` so you can see all the values in the dictionary.